# Typescript array of object

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm trying to use the array of objects and I want to know if my declaration is good ?

```
public async list(){
myObj1 = {
"name": "John",
"age": "45",
"car": 20,
"test": 30,
"example": 20
};
myObj2 = {
"name": "John",
"age": "30",
"car": 10,
"example": 10
};

let tab: Array<{"project": string, "new": string, "old": string}> = []

// find keys
keyObj1 = Object.keys(myObj1);
keyObj2 = Object.keys(myObj2);

// find max length to iterate   
if (keyObj1.length > keyObj2.length) {
  var biggestKey = keyObj1;
} else {
  var biggestKey = keyObj2;
}

// now compare their keys and values 
for (var i = 0; i < biggestKey.length; i++) {
 var key = biggestKey[i];
 if (myObj1[key] != myObj2[key]) {
   tab.push({
     "project": key,
     "new": myObj1[key],
     "old": myObj2[key]
 })
}

//console.log(tab)
}
```

- let tab: Array<{"project": string, "new": string, "old": string}> = []

Just to know if this declaration is good or not ? Because I'm trying to use array of object in TypeScript

Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Your type is fine, however, Typescript will complain about this: `myObj1[key] != myObj2[key]`

Comment: ^^ because you haven't defined an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types-and-index-signatures) for the type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Array<{"project": string, "new": string, "old": string}>` is fine, but:

1. You might not want to have a property called `new` (although it may be an antiquated concern at this point). You **can** have a property with that name, it's just that before ES5, you couldn't use a keyword or reserved word as a literal property name (`x.new` was invalid before ES5, valid in ES5 and later). If you compile your TypeScript to ES3 for use on really old browsers, it'll have to use `x["new"]` everywhere you write `x.new` in order to be compatible with pre-ES5 property identifier syntax.
2. There's no need for the quotes, just `Array<{project: string, new: string, old: string}>` is fine.
3. I would suggest declaring your object type separately (`MyType`, for instance), and then using `MyType[]` instead.

So for instance:

```
interface MyType {
  project: string,
  new: string, // Or possibly change this
  old: string
}
```

and then:

```
let tab: MyType[] = [];
```

Comment: A related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76420420/typescript-how-to-express-an-array-of-objects-as-a-typescript-interface